# How to remove trailing spaces in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I have following code:

```
01 W-IX1                          PIC 9(8) VALUE ZERO COMP-4.

01 W-INPUT-AMNT                   PIC 9(9)V9(5).
01 W-ROUNDED-AMNT                 PIC Z(9).
01 W-TEMP-AMNT                    PIC X(9).
01 W-OUTPUT-AMNT                  PIC X(9).

MOVE 123.92345 TO W-INPUT-AMNT.
MOVE 1 TO W-IX1.

COMPUTE W-ROUNDED-AMNT ROUNDED = W-INPUT-AMNT * 1.
MOVE W-ROUNDED-AMNT TO W-TEMP-AMNT.

INSPECT W-TEMP-AMNT TALLYING W-IX1 FOR LEADING SPACES.
MOVE W-TEMP-AMNT(W-IX1:) TO W-OUTPUT-AMNT.

DISPLAY "RESULT:" W-OUTPUT-AMNT ":".

MOVE SPACE TO W-OUTPUT-AMNT.
```

And following output:

```
RESULT:124      :
```

My intention is to receive following output:

```
RESULT:124:
```

Would appreciate any help. Thx!

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36137284/2025395

Comment: @jchevali - Unfortunately the referenced post was modified to also remove embedded spaces. That does not apply to this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of trailing spaces in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133761/how-do-i-get-rid-of-trailing-spaces-in-a-string)

Comment: There is some confusion because the title you chose matches other posts, although the problem is different. Would you change the title to _How to remove leading and trailing spaces_. Due to changes in the COBOL standard there are other ways to accomplish what you want. Specifically, a `TRIM` function has been added and has been implemented in some newer compilers. It would be good for you to identify the compiler you are using. Doing so could help to provide other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another `INSPECT`, with some other changes, should be all that is necessary.

```
01 W-IX2                          PIC 9(8) VALUE ZERO COMP-4.

MOVE 0 TO W-IX2
INSPECT W-OUTPUT-AMNT TALLYING 
    W-IX2 FOR CHARACTERS BEFORE SPACE.

DISPLAY "RESULT:" W-OUTPUT-AMNT(1:W-IX2) ":".
```

Output:

```
RESULT:124:
```

Comment: This would also replace embedded spaces. The only option without `TRIM` is to... do exactly what the definition of the function `TRIM` is: start from first position until a not-space is found, then start from last position until not space is found, calculate size and do a ref-mod.

Comment: @SimonSobisch - I agree that `TRIM` should be the preferred method, if available; but, in this case, there are no embedded spaces when the suggested additional `INSPECT` statement is executed. COBOL and _only option_ is rarely correct! I'm aware of at least four ways solve this problem. The OP, having used `INSPECT`, it makes sense to go with what the OP has already used.

Comment: I agree that `INSPECT` can be used, but `BEFORE SPACE` would be wrong because of (your own note) to the "possible duplicate" it would have a problem with embedded spaces (as the `UNSTRING` approach would have, too).
A solution with `INSPECT`, that works for embedded spaces, too, would also use an extension not available everywhere with the `TRAILING` phrase.
Despite of *multiple* `UNSTRING` or use of `FUNCTION REVERSE` *or* an intermediate left-/right-aligned field I'm only aware of a manual counting approach, please provide more approaches if you think something different works.

Comment: @SimonSobisch -There are no embedded spaces, therefore, _it would have a problem with embedded spaces_ is a hypothetical. Hypothetically, the only place where spaces (or other non-digits) could occur would be in the original input data. In that case, I might use a "de-edit" `MOVE` to recover the number then proceed with the transformation knowing there are no embedded spaces. The older post had both alpha-numeric and numeric fields, Though not stated, the embedded spaces may have been only in the alpha-numeric fields and thus not applicable to numbers as in this post.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to count backwards from the end of the field to the first non-space character.

```
Preform varying NDX from length of W-OUTPUT-AMT by -1
  until W-OUTPUT-AMT (NDX:1) <> SPACE
     or NDX = 1

DISPLAY "RESULT:" W-OUTPUT-AMNT (1:NDX) ":".
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a different approach, an `UNSTRING` statement may eliminate leading spaces, make trailing spaces irrelevant, and save the number and its length conveniently.

Note that `W-ROUNDED-AMNT` is changed to ensure one leading space and at least one digit.

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 W-IX1                          PIC 9(8) VALUE ZERO COMP-4.

   01 W-INPUT-AMNT                   PIC 9(9)V9(5).
   01 W-ROUNDED-AMNT-X.
     03 W-ROUNDED-AMNT               PIC Z(9)9.
   01 W-X                            PIC X.
   01 W-OUTPUT-AMNT                  PIC X(9).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MOVE 123.92345 TO W-INPUT-AMNT.

       COMPUTE W-ROUNDED-AMNT ROUNDED = W-INPUT-AMNT.

       UNSTRING W-ROUNDED-AMNT-X DELIMITED ALL SPACE
           INTO W-X W-OUTPUT-AMNT COUNT W-IX1

       DISPLAY "RESULT:" W-OUTPUT-AMNT(1:W-IX1) ":".
       MOVE SPACE TO W-OUTPUT-AMNT.

       STOP RUN.
```

Output:

```
RESULT:124:
```

Comment: Intresting approach. Receiving an compiler error in this case: Identifier "W-ROUNDED-AMNT (NUMERIC-EDITED)" was neither an alphanumeric, DBCS, alphanumeric or national function.  The statement was discarded.

Comment: @reto - I inadvertently used an extension that may only be available with Micro Focus.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will not work on all compilers, but I use the following construction to remove trailing spaces and/or compute string lengths. The idea is to reverse the string you're working with, then identify the number of leading spaces. Subtract that number from the length of the string.
This will also preserve any embedded spaces, if present.

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 W-IX1                          PIC 9(8) VALUE ZERO COMP-4.
01 W-TRAIL                        PIC 9(8) VALUE ZERO COMP-4.
01 W-LENGTH                       PIC 9(8) VALUE ZERO COMP-4.

01 W-INPUT-AMNT                   PIC 9(9)V9(5).
01 W-ROUNDED-AMNT                 PIC Z(9).
01 W-TEMP-AMNT                    PIC X(9).
01 W-OUTPUT-AMNT                  PIC X(9).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    MOVE 123.92345 TO W-INPUT-AMNT.
    MOVE 1 TO W-IX1.

    COMPUTE W-ROUNDED-AMNT ROUNDED = W-INPUT-AMNT * 1.
    MOVE W-ROUNDED-AMNT TO W-TEMP-AMNT.

    INSPECT W-TEMP-AMNT TALLYING W-IX1 FOR LEADING SPACES.
    MOVE W-TEMP-AMNT(W-IX1:) TO W-OUTPUT-AMNT.

    MOVE ZERO TO W-TRAIL.

    INSPECT FUNCTION REVERSE (W-OUTPUT-AMNT)
        TALLYING W-TRAIL
        FOR LEADING SPACE.

    SUBTRACT W-TRAIL 
        FROM LENGTH OF W-OUTPUT-AMNT
        GIVING W-LENGTH.

    DISPLAY "RESULT:" W-OUTPUT-AMNT(1:W-LENGTH) ":".

    MOVE SPACE TO W-OUTPUT-AMNT.

    STOP RUN.
```

Answer (score 0):

With Enterprise COBOL V6R2 with APAR PI99703 installed. You can use the TRIM intrinsic function.

```
   Identification division.
   Program-id. TESTTRIM.
   Data division.
   Working-storage section.
   1 msg pic x(20) value "Hello, World!!!   ".
   Procedure division.
       Display ">>" msg "<<"
       Display ">>" function trim(msg) "<<"
       Goback.
```

Output would be:

```
>>Hello, World!!!     <<
>>Hello, World!!!<<
```